# I am working on a VBA code to store all the worksheet changes into an array and before closing use all the "targets" to send out email notifications

Tags: excel, vba

I already have a working code to send out emails when a cell is changed. However I want to wait till all the changes are made in the worksheet and either before closing or after saving I want the email notifications to be sent out. 
The problem I am facing is In Worksheet_change I am not able to store all the target values in an array  and use them in `Before_close` or `After_save` events. Can you please assist me in how to pass those values?

1. For storing values in an array I tried the following :

```vb
Dim DiffAddys() As String, NewValues() As Variant

Application.EnableEvents = False

ReDim DiffAddys(Target.Cells.Count)
ReDim NewValues(Target.Cells.Count)

i = 1 

For Each aCell In Target.Cells

   DiffAddys(i) = aCell.Address
    NewValues(i) = aCell.Value
    i = i + 1
MsgBox (aCell.Value)
MsgBox (DiffAddys(2))
Next aCell
```

2. To get the variable into Before_close, I made both the subs public and tried to use the array as it is.

Comment: If you want to remember all the cells changed in various phases I think you might have to store the number of changes in a cell. Does that sound workable? Otherwise they will be "forgotten" every time you make another change.

Answer (score 0):

You could try declaring the array(s) as Public in a standard (Insert>Module) module.

If you do that though you would probably lose all the values in the arrays if there are errors encountered in the code.